# A continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ such that the integral from zero to infinity exists and $f$ is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Find an example of a continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ such that the integral between zero and infinity exists and f is unbounded.

I have been thinking about this question for quite a while. The function can't have any asymptotes at 0 or any other value otherwise it won't be defined over the interval required, so the function must increase to infinity as x goes to infinity? But I can't find such a function for which the integral is defined.

Comment: Paste together some peaks, the n-th peak being centered at n with height n and width 1/n^3.

Comment: I have tried something very similar, it didn't seem to work. Is there any significance of 1/n^3? I used 1/n^2 but I don't see why there would be any difference. I will go back and try again.

Comment: No, height n and width 1/n^2 would not work, the series of the products height times width, should converge.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. :)

Comment: Is a 'straight lined' peak enough? So its a triangle??

Comment: Yes, for example.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** Can you find a function $f: [n,n+1) \to [0,\infty)$ such that $\int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$, $f(n)=f(n+1)=0$, but $f(n+\frac{1}{2}) > n$?

Try to draw the graph of such a function....

Comment: I think I see where to go thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: $f(x) = x\left ( \frac{2+\sin x}{3} \right )^{x^5}$ is an explicit example.

---

You can see that $((2+\sin x)/3)^{x^5}$ has peaks of $1$ at $\pi/2, 5\pi/2, \dots.$ But when $x$ is large, the $x^5$ power smashes the thing down close to $0$ at other values. From Laplace's method or other estimation, $\int_0^{2\pi}((2+\sin x)/3)^n\,dx$ is on the order of $1/\sqrt n$ as $n\to \infty.$ On the interval $[2n\pi, 2(n+1)\pi],$ you can then expect a contribution to the integral of interest on the order of $n\cdot (1/\sqrt n)^5 = 1/n^{3/2}.$ Because $\sum 1/n^{3/2}<\infty,$ the claim follows.

Comment: You can see that $((2+\sin x)/3)^{x^5}$ has peaks of $1$ at $\pi/2, 5\pi/2, \dots.$ But when $x$ is large, the $x^5$ power smashes the thing down close to $0$ at other values. From Laplace's method or other estimation, $\int_0^{2\pi}((2+\sin x)/3)^n$ is on the order of $1/\sqrt n$ as $n\to \infty.$ On the interval $[2n\pi, 2(n+1)\pi],$ you can then expect a contribution to the integral of interest on the order of $n\cdot (1/\sqrt n)^5 = 1/n^{3/2}.$ $\sum 1/n^{3/2}<\infty$ then does it.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry, I did not mean "comment" in the technical sense... this properly belongs to the answer. I moved it there.